# Hybris Backoffice: how to trigger a create wizard programmatically

Tags: java, java-8, sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to trigger the configurable flow create wizard programmatically through an Action (in java code). Is that possible? Is there a context that can be used to reach the '+' button?

Comment: Do you mean, you are trying to start wizard in action or controller?

Comment: I programmed a button in editor area. This button needs to trigger the create-new item dialogue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to override the item in backoffice-config.xml of your extension.
For example:

```
<context component="create-wizard" type="Employee">
```

then you change the handler to point to your bean:

```
<wz:custom visible="!#empty(newEmpl.uid) and !#empty(newEmpl.name)" handler="myCreateEmployeeHandler" label="Done" />
```

Your myCreateEmployeeHandler class:

```
public class MyCreateEmployeeHandler implements FlowActionHandler {
    // override perform ...
}
```

Hope this helps.